# Getting value of TextArea angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, textarea, angular-ngmodel

I have a textarea:

```
<textarea class="notes" ng-model="notes" placeholder="Some text" style="height: 630px;"></textarea>
```

I then have a button:

```
<button ng-click="saveNotes(notes)"></button>
```

I then have this method in my controller:

```
$scope.saveNotes = function(notes) {
    console.log(notes);
    student.saveNotes(notes, function() {
        console.log("Successfully saved notes.")
    }
)};
```

From what I can tell, notes should return the value of the textarea yet it is consistently returning "undefined". Can anyone spot the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked to make sure they are under the same controller (and therefore the same scope)

Comment: @Binvention They are under the same controller. Is there anything else that might be the reason?

Comment: I would think it's either a problem with notes not being defined before its used in ng model or there is an odd problem with the scopes. I've found the easiest way to manage scopes is to keep the variables assigned to the controller rather then to $scope. It maybe a bit longer but it's easier to tell when you have a scope problem

Comment: For the first explanation you could use ng-init('notes')  for assigning variables to the controller I put an example as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps try assigning your variables to the controller rather then the scope like this

```
<div ng-controller='myController as app'>
<textarea class="notes" ng-model="app.notes" placeholder="Some text" style="height: 630px;"></textarea>
<button ng-click="app.saveNotes(app.notes)"></button>
</div>
```

Then in your code under your controller

```
this.saveNotes = function(notes) {
console.log(notes);
student.saveNotes(notes, function() {
    console.log("Successfully saved notes.")
}
)};
```

In my opinion it just helps prevent conflicting scopes

Answer (score 1):

You retrieve notes' values in "$scope.notes". 
Solution:

```
<button ng-click="saveNotes()"></button>
```

and:

```
$scope.saveNotes = function() {
    console.log($scope.notes);
    student.saveNotes($scope.notes, function() {
        console.log("Successfully saved notes.")
    }
)};
```

Comment: I used your solution but I'm still getting the same error.